# Parse multiple json with retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

This is the structure of my json which i want to send to server from android client using retrofit. i have tried several ways, but nothing worked. Looking for a solution here with your valuable advice. thanx in advance

```
private int studentId;
  private Set<Degrees> studentdegrees;
  private Set<Course> coursenames;
  private Set<CourseAvailability> availabilities;
```

Below is the json

```
{
    "studentId" : 440,
    "firstName" : "nelu",
    "lastName" : "wakaran",
    "dateOfBirth" : "2021-02-02",
        "memberSince" : "2020-01-20",

    "Degrees" :[
        {
        "studentDegree": "xxx",
        "yearOfPassing" : "1985",
        "institutionName" : "xxx",
        "InstitutionLocation" : "xxxx"

        }

    ],
     "course" :[
        {
        "registrationNumber": "xxxx",
        "coursename" : "xxxx",
        "stateCode" : "MH",
        "dateOfregistration" : "2020-01-20",
        "status" : true

        }

    ],
      "avalabilities" :[
        {
        "day": "Friday",
        "sessionStartTime" : "4am",
        "sessionEndTime" : "4am",
     

        }

    ]


}

Created three pojos
Student 
Degree
Course
CourseAvailability
```

**Below is response json**

```
{
    "message": "Student profile updated successfully",
    "status": 200
}
```

**My retrofit call**

```
 @POST("user/updateStudentProfile")
  Call<StudentProfileResponse> addCourse(@Body Student student);
```

This is how i am calling my call in retrofit

```
Call<StudentProfileResponse> responseCall = AppAuthClient.vuAPIServices().addCourse(student);
    responseCall.enqueue(new Callback<StudentProfileResponse>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<StudentProfileResponse> call, @NotNull Response<StudentProfileResponse> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
```

Comment: It works with a `List`, that I know for a fact. I don't see why it would fail for `Set`, but you can actually just create a `List` from a `Set` easily. Need more details tbh.

Comment: updated my question. Can you please check the code and suggest me with how to make a proper retrofit call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting more code, I think I see what the problem is. You're not using the same name for your variable as the expected `json` key. GSON uses your variable name as the default, if not otherwise specified by using `@SerializedName` annotation.
Example:

```
@SerializedName("asdf")
private int variable1;

private int variable2;
```

In this example, `variable1` has the annotation, so that will override the name, and you should get a JSON like `{"asdf": 5, "variable2": 2}`.

In your particular example, I think you should add `@SerializedName` annotations to most (if not all) of your variables, just to avoid confusion.

```
@SerializedName("studentId") // not mandatory, cause they're the same
private int studentId;
@SerializedName("Degrees") // CaseSensitive, pay good attention, the JSON must match verbatim
private Set<Degrees> studentdegrees;
@SerializedName("course")
private Set<Course> coursenames;
@SerializedName("availabilities")
private Set<CourseAvailability> availabilities;
```

Comment: E/TAG: onFailure: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Body parameter value must not be null. (parameter #1)
        for method VuAPIServices.addCourse

Comment: I implemented it as per your suggestion in the code but i m constantly getting the above error

Comment: Well bro, that's a new error completely. Google it. It has to do with some parameters in the POST method being null or something. It is not strictly related to the error that we have just fixed. Consider accepting the answer in order to close this thread. Ask another question should you not be able to figure it out on your own. Cheers.